# AES_DECRYPT() and AES_ENCRYPT() in MySQL with Polish characters

Tags: c#, mysql, encryption, aes

I have a MySQL database which is configured to receive a data with polish characters (f. ex ą, ę, ó, ł, ń etc.).

Now I want to send data with these Polish characters to a db using `AES_ENCRYPT()`, and then get them from there using `AES_DECRYPT()`.
My problem is that I receive a byte[] array in C# which has X elements where X is length of text I receive. And every single array element has an ASCII code of an character it represents. I could easily convert it to text using Encoding Class, but I won't get Polish characters in output text.

F. ex.:

I send `AES_ENCRYPT('ąąą', '123')` to db.
I get `AES_DECRYPT('sql command','123')` and I get `byte[]` which has 3 elements, everyone with '97' value which represents `'aaa'` - NOT `'ąąą'`. 
How to use `AES_DECRYPT/ENCRYPT` in a way which allows me to send/get polish characters to my DB?!
Or how to get string output from aes_decrypt() instead byte[]?

Answer (score 4):

convert using encoding might help you.

```
select convert(aes_decrypt(aes_encrypt('ąąą', 'abcdefg'), 'abcdefg') using UTF8);
```

Comment: Hmm, when I do it in MySQL WorkBench - IT WORKS! It has Polish characters! But when I use `ExecuteScalar()` in my C# code I still get string without polish characters. Any Ideas? How to convert it in C#?

Comment: I think you need to find string encoding method in C# Encoding.Convert

Comment: what's result when you call ExecuteScalar().

Comment: The result is string but without polish characters. Which is weird because MySQL Wrokbench (the same command) is returning string WITH polish characters!

Comment: have you try encode before encrypt  `aes_encrypt(convert('ąąą' using UTF8), 'abcdefg')`

Comment: I found that when I insert the same text using AES_ENCRYPT from my C# program and from mysql workbench (the same command!) the encrypted data in db is different! Why is that? Now i'm gonna test convert it to utf8 when inserting.

Comment: I tried to convert text using UTF8 before aes_encrypt() but it doesn't work. How it is possible that 2 THE SAME mysql QUERIES, one executed in workbench another one in c# program, gives two different values in db?!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just implement encryption/decryption in code instead of in queries?

```
private static Byte[] Encrypt(String toEncrypt, Byte[] Key, Byte[] IV)
{
    CryptoStream streamCrypto = null;
    MemoryStream streamMemory = null;
    RijndaelManaged aes = null;
    StreamWriter streamWriter = null;

    try
    {
        aes = new RijndaelManaged();
        aes.Key = Key;
        aes.IV = IV;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        streamMemory = new MemoryStream();
        streamCrypto = new CryptoStream(streamMemory, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(streamCrypto);

        streamWriter.Write(toEncrypt);

    }
    finally
    {
        if (streamWriter != null)
            streamWriter.Close();

        if (streamCrypto != null)
            streamCrypto.Close();

        if (streamMemory != null)
            streamMemory.Close();

        if (aes != null)
            aes.Clear();
    }

    return streamMemory.ToArray();
}

public static String Decrypt(Byte[] toDecrypt, Byte[] Key, Byte[] IV)
{
    CryptoStream streamCrypto = null;
    MemoryStream streamMemory = null;
    RijndaelManaged aes = null;
    StreamReader streamReader = null;
    String output = null;

    try
    {
        aes = new RijndaelManaged();
        aes.Key = Key;
        aes.IV = IV;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        streamMemory = new MemoryStream(toDecrypt);
        streamCrypto = new CryptoStream(streamMemory, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        streamReader = new StreamReader(streamCrypto);

        output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (streamReader != null)
            streamReader.Close();

        if (streamCrypto != null)
            streamCrypto.Close();

        if (streamMemory != null)
            streamMemory.Close();

        if (aes != null)
            aes.Clear();
    }

    return output;
}
```

In your code, you encrypt your string and then you send encrypted data to the database:

```
Byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(yourString, Key, IV);
```

When you pull out data from the database, you just get back your string using:

```
String decrypted = Decrypt(dbData, Key, IV);
```

If you don't like this way, just use your queries like so:

```
INSERT INTO mysecrets (mysecret1, mysecret2) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT(secret1, YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY), AES_ENCRYPT(secret2, YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY))

SELECT AES_DECRYPT(mysecret1, YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY) AS secret1, AES_DECRYPT(mysecret1, YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY) AS secret2 FROM mysecrets
```

Comment: It's a lot of work to do. First I want to try to do it using mysql functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL data is in characters, while encryption works on bytes.  You need to convert your characters to bytes before encrypting them, and also convert the decrypted bytes back to characters.  That means you need to explicitly specify the character encoding to be used at both ends so they match.  The current standard is UTF-8, so you should specify that at each end.  If UTF-8 does not work, then try some Microsoft specific character encoding at both ends.

Comment: Ok, now I'll try yours idea.I have converted string to byte[] using `byte[] bytes=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string);`but how to insert these bytes PROPERLY into my varchar() column?

Comment: I am not a MySQL expert, but bytes are *not* characters.  You need a column that will hold binary data, varbytes (?), BLOB or something similar.