# MySQL: No results with umlaut in LIKE

Tags: mysql, aes

I have a table with encrypted data and I want to search for a value with LIKE but when the value has a umlaut (f.ex ä, ö, ü), it doesn't work.

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(test, 'KEY') AS test FROM table WHERE AES_DECRYPT(test, 'KEY') LIKE '%Ä%'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AES\_DECRYPT() and AES\_ENCRYPT() in MySQL with Polish characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414800/aes-decrypt-and-aes-encrypt-in-mysql-with-polish-characters)

Comment: I can't duplicate this offhand; what type is table.test?  what character set is your connection using?

Comment: Specify correct COLLATE (and, maybe, even CHARSET) to your comparing expression.

Comment: @ysth The table is with charset: utf8mb; collation: utf8mb4_general_ci and table.test is a longblob (aes encrypted)

Comment: @Akina I have tried it now with: SELECT AES_DECRYPT(test, 'KEY') AS test FROM table WHERE CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(test, 'KEY') USING utf8) LIKE '%Ä%' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci but it doesn't help

Comment: *charset: utf8mb;* ?? I know utf8, itf8mb3 and utf8mb4. *table.test is a longblob* it must use some utf8mb4 binary collation. Check real collatoin in SHOW CREATE TABLE and use it in the query.

Comment: @Akina Oh, alright - SHOW CREATE Table returns CHARSET=latin1; COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci. Fyi: The values with the umlauts are in utf8_decoded (in latin1). Is there a possibility to convert my LIKE string also to latin1?

Comment: Use explicit `CONVERT(USING)` function - it can this.